# Why can't I create multiple subscriptions for a customer profile with the same amount and interval?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I am using the PHP SDK to create Subscriptions for customers in the following flow.

Create customer -> add payment profile -> create subscription.

The first subscription is created perfectly. After that if I try to create a subscription that on my side is a different subscription but has the same amount, interval, and occurrences I get the following error.

> Error Code E00012
>
> "You have submitted a duplicate of Subscription 4362497. A duplicate
>   subscription will not be created."

The issue I have with this is that I'm passing a different refId and a different subscription name.

Is there anyway to create multiple subscriptions that have the same amount, interval and occurrences? There must be some way to define a different subscription that has those other fields the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Authorize.Net](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A116&pmv=print):

> The ARB system checks a new subscription for duplicates, using these
>   fields:
>
> - subscription.article.merchantID
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.payment.creditCard.cardNumber
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.payment.eCheck.routingNumber
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.payment.eCheck.accountNumber
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.customerID
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.firstName
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.lastName
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.company
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.streetAddress
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.city
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.stateProv
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.zip
> - subscription.orderInfo.amount
> - subscription.orderInfo.invoice
> - subscription.recurrence.startDate
> - subscription.recurrence.interval
> - subscription.recurrence.unit
>
> If all of these fields are duplicated in an existing subscription,
>   E00012 will result. Modifying any of these fields should result in a
>   unique subscription.

The invoice number seems like the best field to modify to make each subscription unique.